# Given the sums by line and by column, find the corresponding matrix (in a general (complete ?) monoid or semiring)

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, matrices, infinitary-combinatorics, semiring

I'm interested in the following question:

> In a monoid $\mathbf{M}$, given sums $\sum_{i \in I} a_i = \sum_{j \in J} b_j$, is it possible to find elements $c_{i,j}$ such that
>
> - for all $i$, $a_i = \sum_{j \in J} c_{i,j}$,
> - and for all $j$, $b_i = \sum_{i \in I} c_{i,j}$ ?

This amounts to find an $I \times J$ matrix such that $a_i$ (resp. $b_j$) is the sum of the $i$th row (resp. $j$th column).

In addition:

- Working within the assumption that $I$ and $J$ are (at most) countable is enough for me.
- The fact that the $a_i$ and $b_j$ describe (possibly) infinite sums carries the implicit assumption that these sums are well-defined. In practice we can restrict to complete monoids (and our real-life example is $\overline{\mathbf{R}_+} = \mathbf{R}_+ \cup \{\infty\}$).

I think my colleagues and I found a proof that this is always possible provided some good assumptions are satisfied (completeness, total ordering), but our proof is quite convoluted and doesn't seem very general. So that's my question: **Is this problem known? Does it have a name? Has it been addressed somewhere? Does anybody know anything about this?**

Comment: I found out this property is called "additive splitting" here: https://www.irif.fr/~ehrhard/pub/relexpl.pdf (and in a few papers following this one).

Comment: I edited the question: I initially formulated it in a semiring, but it is only about sums so it is valid in any monoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been studied under the name [*refinement monoid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refinement_monoid).